# Where are the firefox favorites stored in windows?

Tags: firefox, explorer, favorites

I would like to have a clean up of my Firefox favorites as its been a good 4 years of adding but not deleting from it.

Where could i view the favorites so i can browser them in Windows Explorer?

I'm using Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you export them? after that you can save them into your local hard drive as a backup for a future restore if you want.